# Javascript How to return a value back to the invoking function

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, return

For this Javascript example, can somebody please explain on a very basic level why this is not working and how you properly create another (not nested) function that passes back a value to the function it was invoked from.

```
function function1() {
    var x = 5;

    function2(x);
    console.log(y);

    function3(y);
    console.log(z);
}   

function function2(y) {
    var y = y + 5;
    return y;
}

function function3(z) {
    var z = z + 5;
    return z;
}
```

Even when declaring them in the main function, it doesn't work:

```
function function1() {
    var x = 5;

    var y = function2(x);
    console.log(y);

    var z = function3(y);
    console.log(z);
```

When using global variables, no difference. I also tried following other examples where you create 1 global object to write global variables to, but that also always fails with "undefined":

```
function function1() {
    x = 5;

    y = function2(x);
    console.log(y);

    z = function3(y);
    console.log(z);
```

I guess I don't understand some very basic concept. Please shine some light.  I can see subroutines running and doing what they need to do, but they never pass back the final value to the function that invoked the function.

**Follow up question**

I do a request to an API where I get a roomId. Next I try to call a function that does another API call to translate the roomId to a roomName. I want to pass the roomName back to the other function to use it there. I tried many things already, untill now not able to pass back the variable. As the previous example seem to work, it must have something to do with something else (array/object, string/nostring/...).

```
    function GetMemberships() {

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "HIDDEN";
    var method = "GET";
    var shouldBeAsync = true;

    xhttp.open(method, url, shouldBeAsync);

    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer HIDDEN"); // API key of Bot

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            var roomId = jsonObj.items[0].roomId;
            var roomId = JSON.stringify(roomId);
            var roomId = roomId.replace(/"/g,'');
            var roomName = GetNameOfRoom(roomId);
            console.log(roomName)  // UNDEFINED
        }
    };

    xhttp.send();
}


function GetNameOfRoom(roomId) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "HIDDEN" + roomId;
    var method = "GET";
    var shouldBeAsync = true;

    xhttp.open(method, url, shouldBeAsync);

    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer HIDDEN");

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            var roomName = jsonObj.title;
            console.log(roomName);  // SHOWS CORRECT VALUE
            return roomName;
        }
    };

    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: don't use `function function2(x)` when calling the function. just `function2(x)`.

Comment: ```function function2(x);``` This is not valid javasacript. I guess you are getting an ```Unexpected token ;``` error. To define a nested function, you have to write its block as well like ```function function2() { /* do something */ }```. To call a function, discard the ```function``` token.

Comment: Sorry, the example was bad. I changed the example, as I just call the function. It doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

So first you need a function invoke in which you declare your variables and assign them a certain value:

```
function invoke() {
    var x, y = 0;

    x = h(21);
    y = g(42);

    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
}
```

Then you create the functions in which you do your calculations:

```
function h(n) {
    return n + 5;
}

function g(n) {
    return n - 5;
}
```

Now you just need to call your function invoke in order to execute it:

```
invoke();
```

If you want to print out the calculations as well, add:

```
function invoke2(x,y) {
    console.log(h(x));
    console.log(g(y));
}
invoke2(21,42);
```

That should give you your result.

Comment: I hope that this´ll help you!